# Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0,1]} x\cos(\frac{x}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0,1]} x\cos(\frac{x}{n})$.

So, I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem? I could use the Vitali convergence theorem, since the domain is finite. Struggling with this one, would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$ right...?

Comment: Hint: Use Lebesgue and that the integrand goes to $x$ as $n\to\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|x \cos(\frac x n) | \leq x$ and $x$ is integrable on $[0,1]$. Hence the limit is $\int_0^{1}x dx=\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Okay, so we have a dominating function, but don't we also need the pointwise limit of $x cos(\frac{x}{n})$? Doesn't this function have no limit?

Comment: Wowww My mistake I see